# Can I have run and knit give the same results with external code?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Since I have some fairly large code chunks (plantuml charts, sql), I'd prefer to keep those as external files. I see in the knitr manual I can do something like `code=readLines(...)` to bring in outside sources.

When using external code this way, I'm seeing a difference in behavior between running the chunk in RStudio with the green play button, and knitting the code.

With these two files:

*main.R*:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Me"
date: "6/17/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(here)
library(xfun)
```

```{r, code=xfun::read_utf8(here::here('test.R'))}
print('world')
```
````

and *test.R*:

```
print('hello')
```

when I knit, `hello` is printed. When I run the code chunks using run in RStudio, or `restart R and run all chunks`, then the preview says `world`. The `print('world')` here is just to illustrate that the inline code is being ran; in my case, the inline code would be empty.

I see in the comments that "Knitr will replace the code in the chunk with the code in the code option", but does that mean that separate chunks are not run by knitr by another environment? Can I do something to have the external code be executed by both rather than one executing the inline code and the other the external code?

Comment: This is as intended. From here: https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf?_ga=2.265489423.1827680765.1593535595-1544217322.1580338617 "Knitr will replace the code in the chunk with the code in the code option"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not an actual error.

Comment: OK, I understand now -- the code-loading is something knitr-specific, the direct-run is not. I agree that this is not a bug then. Can I change my question to an "how can this be accomplished?" I still need the same behavior.

Comment: Why not use two separate chunks?

Comment: My use case is that I have fairly large plantuml and sql chunks, and I'd prefer to have them external, but also have preview work. Two separate chunks don't help there - I'd still have to have the source inline, and then I might as well just use only that.

Comment: No wait - I don't understand. In the default case with an inline body, something is feeding the chunk body to the engine, but for run and knit. Isn't it knitr in both cases that does this? If it is, why should it make any difference how options$code gets populated?

Comment: I'd suggest editing further to get the the root of the problem. "I have a large piece of code that I'd like to keep externally, but I'd still like the preview to work" seems to be the gist of it. With the code example you show, you presume a particular answer and perhaps complicate thingsbecause we actively need to ignore the `print('world')`...

Comment: Better in the current state?

Comment: I have found https://community.rstudio.com/t/what-is-the-difference-between-running-chunk-and-knitting-it/40222/7 -- seems like what I want just isn't possible.